# Can not find record in Recordset ADO

Tags: c++, sql-server, ado, recordset

I'm using ADO with C++ and i have problem about finding specific record in Recordset.I wrote Connection to database, Recordset.Open and etc... So everything going well. And which record I want to find is already exists in Database but Recordset->Find method could not find that particular data in Recordset. Could you look at my code and tell me where am i go wrong? or is this correct syntax of writing Recordset->Find() method P.S I'm new in ADO, so i don't know if this is correct syntax. Thank you in advance.

i have already tried to return record by Fields->GetItem and it works. it returns "nikala".(if it does matters.) so that means Recordset is opening well.
`_bstr_t AccReturn = pRecst->Fields->GetItem("Account")->Value;`

My Code:

```
pRecst->MoveFirst();
bool found = pRecst->Find("[Account] = 'nikala'", 0, adSearchForward);
if(found == true)
{
    //update code
}
else
{
    //insert into DB
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample:

1. Open Curror

   pRecst->Open("SELECT * FROM TABLE", 
            _variant_t((IDispatch *)pConnection),
   adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText);

   pRecst->MoveFirst();

   pRecst->Find("Account = 'nikala'", 0, adSearchForward);
2. Check record exists with the EndOfFile property:

   bool found = !pRecst->EndOfFile;